# How can i secure my wamp/www/Folder-name so that no one can play with the contents of my website

Tags: wamp

I have created a local server in my computer lab and hosted a website on it so that people on same network can use it.I am using wamp and php for my website. The computer which is made server is also used by some students so I want to secure my website from being **stolen** or **any changes in the code** by students. How can I do it?
My website is stored at the location **wamp/www/my-website**

Comment: You will have to move the server onto a box that is not used by others. Like all servers

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly for your quick reply. Admin will not allow a different computer for it. Is there no way to do it? Can we apply some folder-lock or something like that?